# How to fetch particular objects by their attribute from Array?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I need to get objects with special attribute **"type"** out of Array. These objects I am going to assign to scope. How can I do this?

The following approach didn't work out for me.

```
$scope.vendors = {}
$scope.clients = {}

$scope.loadCounterparties = function() {
  Counterpartie.query(function(response) {

    $scope.vendors = response.type.Vendor;
    $scope.clients = response.type.Client

  });
};
```

Response objects look like this

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular doesn't have something dedicated for this. You need to filter the arrays via plain java script. However you can try using a `3rd party library by the name underscore.js.`
It adds many usefull functions like "where":

_.where(list, properties) 
Looks through each value in the list, returning an array of all the values that contain all of the key-value pairs listed in properties.

> _.where(listOfPlays, {author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611});
>   => [{title: "Cymbeline", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611},
>       {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611}]

Here is a link to the library's page
http://underscorejs.org/#where

Answer (score 1):

can use angular forEach but I would use lodash

```
// assuming one array and two search arguments i.e. client and vendor  
var data = response;
$scope.loadCounterparties = _.filter(data, {type: 'Vendor', type:     'Client'});
```